# Do I need to std::move or std::forward to base constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11

If I have a class from a library that has move constructors. I derive from this class, and want to pass through to a base constructor:

```
class MyDerived : LibraryBase
{
public:
    MyDerived( LibraryBase&& b ) : LibraryBase(b) {}
};
```

Is that right, or do I need something like this to select the base class's move constructor?

```
    MyDerived( LibraryBase&& b ) : LibraryBase(std::move(b)) {}
```

Comment: Your `MyDerived` move-constructor may only get rvalue references. But once you get there, that reference is bound to the name `b` which makes it an lvalue. So I would expect `LibraryBase`'s copy-constructor to be called unless you move or forward. You could test this by adding some prints in your constructors.

Comment: Don't forget if you're just "forwarding" to to the base then you can just inherit the constructors instead with:

class MyDerived : LibraryBase
{
public:
    using LibraryBase::LibraryBase;
};